# magento site shipping charges not working in Android App

Tags: android, magento, soap

app/code/local/com/extension/Model/Carrier/Localdelivery.php

```
<?php
class comp_extension_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    /* Use group alias */
    protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){
        //skip if not enabled
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')||Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/mp_multi_shipping/active')){
           return false;
        }

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $postcode=$session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $countrycode=$session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode);
        /****/
        foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }

     public function getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail) {
        $shippinginfo=array();
        $handling=0;
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $customerAddress = $session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        foreach($shippingdetail as $shipdetail) {
            $seller = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($shipdetail['seller_id']);
            $sellerAddress = $seller->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            $distance = $this->getDistanse($sellerAddress->getPostcode(),$customerAddress->getPostcode());
            $price = 0;
            $itemsarray=explode(',',$shipdetail['item_id']);
            foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $proid=$item->getProductId();
                $options=$item->getProductOptions();
                $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
                if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                    foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                            $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                $mpshippingcharge = 0;
                $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
                $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
                $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
                if(in_array($item->getId(),$itemsarray)) {
                    if($mpassignproductId) {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getStateShippingCharge();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpStateShippingCharge();
                        }   
                    }
                    if(floatval($mpshippingcharge)==0){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount'));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+$mpshippingcharge;
                    }
                }
            }

            $handling = $handling+$price;
            $submethod = array(array('method'=>Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'),'cost'=>$price,'error'=>0));
            array_push($shippinginfo,array('seller_id'=>$shipdetail['seller_id'],'methodcode'=>$this->_code,'shipping_ammount'=>$price,'product_name'=>$shipdetail['product_name'],'submethod'=>$submethod,'item_ids'=>$shipdetail['item_id']));
        }
        $msg="";
        return array('handlingfee'=>$handling,'shippinginfo'=>$shippinginfo,'errormsg'=>$msg);
    }

    private function getDistanse($origin,$destination) {
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$origin.",india&destinations=".$destination.",india&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_all = json_decode($response);
        $distance = $response_all->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value / 1000;
        return $distance;
    }
}
```

we have marketplace **multi vendor/seller** site. we are doing Android App for the site....

we are using custom Shipping method  in our site.

This shipping method is based on "**seller" & "Buyer**" **zip** code. we save seller zip code in Backend. we set the how much shipping charges according to distance in Backend. Once Buyer enter the zip code in shipping address , it will calculate the  shipping charges between seller and buyer based on distance.

This is working fine in site.

But in Android app, we are calling this API to get shipping methods : **shoppingCartShippingList()**

we are getting shipping method , but we are getting shipping charges as zero.

Above i posted extension code responsible for getting shipping charges :

Comment: Is api response not showing charges properly or there is some problem with android app??

Comment: yes, in App it showing shipping charges as "zero" only. it not showing properly. i dont think there is problem with android app. because for other shipping methods, in app we are getting shiping charges correctly.....